# While moving GPS Lat/Long values intermittantly don't change

Tags: gps, nmea

I have been using the [SIM28](http://www.simcom.eu/index.php?m=termekek&prime=1&sub=2&id=0000000244) GPS module and have a problem. The problem is that the GPS latitude and longitude values don't change while the device moves, sometimes the latitude and longitude values remain the same for up to two minutes or longer.  This occurs around 50% of the time the GPS unit is running.  When the GPS values recover (start changing again) there is a large jump to the actual position.

My configuration is:

- Two SIM28 GPS modules running in tandem.
- Each module has a good antenna (http://php2.twinner.com.tw/files/onshine/ANT555-2006-NEW.pdf).  The GPS antenna is mounted inside a radio controlled RC sailboat with a thin plastic hull (but had the same problem when mounted outside).
- The baud rate is set to 9600
- The NMEA rate is 4 Hz
- The NMEA sentences returned are GGA and RMC.

The funny thing is that both GPS units do the same thing at similar times.

One thing that could be a factor could be the roll of the sailboat (how the sailboat rolls to the side when the wind blows), but I did some analysis and I don't see a correlation here. **Update:** The SIM28 module also has this problem in clear open area with direct view of the sky.

Below is an example of the output (of just one receiver and only GGA sentence).  The "good" values are labeled with `#`:

```
    $GPGGA,212131.500,3648.5591,S,17445.0304,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7C # 
    $GPGGA,212131.750,3648.5591,S,17445.0304,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7B # 
    $GPGGA,212132.000,3648.5590,S,17445.0305,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7A # 
    $GPGGA,212132.250,3648.5590,S,17445.0306,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7E # 
    $GPGGA,212132.500,3648.5590,S,17445.0307,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7D # 
    $GPGGA,212132.750,3648.5590,S,17445.0307,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7A # 
    $GPGGA,212133.000,3648.5590,S,17445.0308,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*76 # 
    $GPGGA,212133.250,3648.5590,S,17445.0309,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*70 # 
    $GPGGA,212133.500,3648.5590,S,17445.0310,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7A # 
    $GPGGA,212133.750,3648.5590,S,17445.0310,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7D # 
    $GPGGA,212134.000,3648.5590,S,17445.0311,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*79
    $GPGGA,212134.250,3648.5591,S,17445.0311,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7F # 
    $GPGGA,212134.500,3648.5591,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7E # 
    $GPGGA,212134.750,3648.5591,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.0,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*79 # 
    $GPGGA,212135.000,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*78
    $GPGGA,212135.250,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7F # 
    $GPGGA,212135.500,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7D
    $GPGGA,212135.750,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7A
    $GPGGA,212136.000,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7B
    $GPGGA,212136.250,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7C
    $GPGGA,212136.500,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7E
    $GPGGA,212136.750,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*79
    $GPGGA,212137.000,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7A
    $GPGGA,212137.250,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7D
    $GPGGA,212137.500,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*7F
    $GPGGA,212137.750,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*78
    $GPGGA,212138.000,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*75
    $GPGGA,212138.250,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*72
    $GPGGA,212138.500,3648.5592,S,17445.0312,E,2,11,0.86,3.1,M,26.5,M,0000,0000*70
```

Comment: It appears that the SIM28 may be buggy.  I tried a u-blox NEO-6M and it works without any issues.  It appears the SIM28 may do some position smoothing, because if you have the device stationary the GPS values are exactly stationary too (you would expect this in an ideal world).  However, the u-blox NEO-6M is noisier and the position will always fluctuate.  I actually prefer the fluctuation over the smoothing.  However, it would be good to get someone's expert opinion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem is with the SIM28 GPS module.  I have used the u-blox NEO-6M module and it works well.

My guess is the SIM28 has some buggy noise filtering.  The u-blox is tends to noisier, but I prefer to be able to filter the noise myself than let the GPS unit do it.